# A* algorithm open list selection

Tags: algorithm, a-star

I understand that in the A* algorithm when taking the next step the step with the next lowest predicted cost should be chosen from the openlist or frontier, but when there is multiple lowest steps all with the same predicted cost is there any preference for which one should be chosen?

I think last on first off could work better, but I'm not sure if there is a better way to select the next move when there are multiple matching costs.

Comment: I removed your MATLAB tag as this is a more algorithmic question and is independent of the implementation language.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to A*, all the steps with equal estimated cost (cost from start plus heuristic) are equally worth investigating.

The thing is that, without further heuristic, i's difficult to make the choice; or, rather, it depends on what you want.

In the standard `f(x) = g(x) + h(x)` case, if you have no other heuristic or information, there are 2 main strategies:

- you choose the most recent step `x`, hoping that it corresponds to a good track (and it might help for memory locality issues): if it's recent, it means that it only got a relatively minor cost update with respect to the others;
- you choose the step `x` with the smallest `h`, that is, for which the relative contribution of the know cost is highest with respect to unknown cost (that's what weighted A* aims for).

For this second strategy, beside inflating the heuristic, you just need to order your steps/nodes by the pair `(f, h)` instead of just `f`. It will however not guarantee that you don't have ties:

```
 *
/ \
| |
\ /
 +
```

In the end, you'll need to choose one, for example the most recent (or just the one that your implementation of priority queue yields).

Note that if you choose `x` with the most `h`, you'll get closer to the breadth behavior Amit was referring to.

Answer (score 1):

I think you are looking for [bounded relaxation (AKA A*-epsilon)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A*_search_algorithm#Bounded_relaxation).

The idea is to generate `f(v) = g(v) + (1+eps)h(v)`. With very small value of `eps`, it does not change the optimality of the algorithm, while favoring "depth" over "breadth" in the search, and often increasing the search's speed.

Similarly, you can favor breadth by giving very close to zero but negative value of `eps` - but I am not familiar with any usage of favoring breadth here.

Comment: Well, that's not exactly the answer to the question. What you suggest (and is working well but you still run the risk of losing optimality) is to change the cost of the steps, but the question is about how to choose in case of equal cost (which would also happen in your case).

Comment: @FrancisColas Think what happens when eps>0, but very small, effectively `eps = 1/infinity`. It is enough to tie break between two nodes such that `g(v) = x, h(v) = y` and `g(u) = x-c, h(v) = y+c`, and will favor `v` over `u` (and effectively tie breaking nodes with identical `g` value to favor depth). If `eps` is chosen to be small enough, it is not going to affect optimality, since every eps-optimal solution is optimal.

Comment: I'm familiar with the concept but there are two cases you overlook. If your graph has continuous costs, you have no clue about the epsilon that still guarantees optimality (it might be important for some applications (that's probably not OP's case since that typically leads to very few ties)). If you're in a grid world with uniform cost (that's where you get plenty of ties), then your heuristic is also structured and you changing the heuristic doesn't guarantee you got rid of ties (think having an obstacle in the middle and having to choose between left or right). You still need to break ties.

Comment: @FrancisColas There is no silver bullet, but it does break some important ties. Have a look back at your grid example, no obstacles and need to move from (0,0) to (n,n). Regular A* will always have all nodes `g(v) = 2n`, and picking a node is going to be random, and if done in queue - it is going to decay to BFS. However, with this approach, you are going to favor depth and travel directly to the target, effectively making A* run extremely faster (2n nodes to develop compared to n^2).

Comment: Don't get me wrong, that's definitely useful. But it's not the same algorithm and it doesn't fully get rid of the choice issue.

Comment: I agree with @FrancisColas, Introducing an eps. doesn't solve the "course of action" issue for the entirety of the cost i.e. f(v)

Answer (score 0):

In theory, neither is a better choice than the other because your fitness function is supposed to model which is better than the other using all available information.

Pick whichever one is easiest to program, the most recent, or your favorite `ith` prime on the list. It shouldn't matter.

Answer (score 0):

A good choice for breaking the ties might be picking the node with greatest G value, after all they will be closer to the end point.

The idea came from here
http://movingai.com/astar.html

On that page there are videos showing the difference between breaking ties by picking the lowest G and picking the highest.

Unfortunately there are no videos showing "greatest G" vs "last node". As Francis mentioned on his answer, using the last one may be more cache friendly and result in better speeds. Add that to the fact that simply using the last one may require less book-keeping code...

That same site has a bunch of real game maps and test scenarios you can use to benchmark which works better. You can find them here http://movingai.com/benchmarks/

My tests, using my own A* implementation have shown that... it all depends on the map/scenario :)

Overall, using the maps and scenarios from the link above and my own A* implementation, breaking ties by simply picking the last node wins 90% of the time. On the other hand, there are a few maps where breaking the ties by picking the highest G wins 90% of the time.

I would love to hear how it goes for you.